# Missing Epson printer driver

Tags: printer

I started using Loki 0.4 and wanted to install my Epson XP-415 All-in-one printer. It got recognized and the OS wanted to install the driver but a message appeared: "Missing printer driver, no printer driver for EPSON XP-412-413-415". I couldn't find a driver on Epson's page for Deb based linux for manual install. What should I do t get it running under Elementary (love the OS by the way!).

Greets, Joris 
(The Netherlands)

---

**Thank you, this is the website you mean for Epson, hadn't found it before:**

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

**I tried your answer below but there are missing dependencies:**

~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg --install epson-inkjet-printer-201301w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

(Reading database ... 246591 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack epson-inkjet-printer-201301w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-201301w (1.0.0-1lsb3.2) over (1.0.0-1lsb3.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-201301w:
 epson-inkjet-printer-201301w depends on lsb (>= 3.2); however:
  Package lsb is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-201301w (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-201301w

**Then just**

apt-get -f install

Which takes a while... *ran first command again*, turned on printer, waited for OS to install, did a testprint and

**YES! It printed perfectly.**

Comment: Thank you! I edited the answer. You might want to correct/complete it and accept it once it is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-XP-412_413_415_Series

You should install the **amd64 deb** package from this site, download it and use the command line

```
user@machine:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg --install epson-inkjet-printer-201301w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```

After this you might have to install missing depenencies as well:

```
user@machine:~/sudo apt install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this slightly differently.  I found the [epson-escpr driver](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-escpr) on open-printing.org.  I installed the DEB [distribution](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb) - amd x86 64 bit.  at the command line:

`sudo apt install ./epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`

Next, I went to appcenter > printers > Clicked Open (it was greyed out, but it did open) > Found my Epson xp-820 listed (USB).  I walked through the menus to find my printer and install it.  It immediately recognized it as an XP-820 and added the printer to my printer list in the "printers" app UI.

Note that before I installed the amd driver from open drivers, the "printers" app made me select a driver and installed it wrong.  Print test page didn't print correctly.